# Alternative way to solve "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: fs.writeFile is not a function" for tensorflow js running in chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have been trying to export a variable in the the tensorflow posenet model running in chrome browser in the code snippet below. However reading through  discussions , it seems one cannot export a variable using fswritefile in the chrome browser. I was  wondering if there is any other possible way to export to json file ? if some one has managed it ?

```
export function drawKeypoints(keypoints, minConfidence, ctx, scale = 1) {
  for (let i = 0; i < keypoints.length; i++) {
    const keypoint = keypoints[i];

    if (keypoint.score < minConfidence) {
      continue;
    }

    const {y, x} = keypoint.position;
    drawPoint(ctx, y * scale, x * scale, 3, color);
  }
  //console.log(keypoints);
 let test = JSON.stringify(keypoints);
 fs.writeFile('extract.json', test, (err) => {  
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Data written to file');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fs is a nodejs specific module. It can't be used in the browser. 
Blob saving to a file is the standard way of writing to a file in the browser environment

Answer (score 0):

Fs is Node.js/commonJS module and you need an equivalent browser-based ES6 supported module. In my personal experience,I had to use Fs wrapper in browser like [browserfs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserfs), [browserify-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-fs) or [fs-es6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-es6) as a workaround.